# Why doesn't my toast notification code work?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to show toast notification when downloading is completed.But it doesn't work.Why doesn't work ?

```
if (download.Progress.Status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed)
        {
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

            XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello toast"));

            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(CoreApplication.Id).Show(toast);
        }
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Is there an error message? If yes, on what line does the exception occur? Have you debugged the method and checked the values of the XML?

Comment: There isn't any error message. I debugged and checked values. I don't find any bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure your app is toast-capable in the app manifest?

Comment: Damn. I'm newbie Windows 8 development. It's very easy, I forget. Thanks.